# What are the differences between typescript access modifiers and javascript ones? And which one should I prefer while using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visibility, member, access-modifiers

Typescript offers the `public`,`protected` and `private` keywords for defining the visibility of the member or the method declared next to them, however, I know that since ES6 Javascript allow the use of the prefix "#" to a class member or method in order to achieve the same result.

To try to have a better understanding of how all works behind the scenes I wrote a toy-class in Typescript just to see how it compiles in javascript:

```
class aClass
{
    #jsPrivate: number;
    get jsPrivate()
        { return this.#jsPrivate};

    private tsPrivate: number;
    protected tsProtected: number;
    public tsPublic: number;

    constructor( a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number)
    {
        this.#jsPrivate = a;
        this.tsPrivate = b;
        this.tsProtected = c;
        this.tsPublic = d;
    }
}

console.log(new aClass(1,2,3,4));
```

that compiled using `tsc --target es6` with Typescript version 4.3.5 becomes:

```
var __classPrivateFieldSet = (this && this.__classPrivateFieldSet) || function (receiver, state, value, kind, f) {
    if (kind === "m") throw new TypeError("Private method is not writable");
    if (kind === "a" && !f) throw new TypeError("Private accessor was defined without a setter");
    if (typeof state === "function" ? receiver !== state || !f : !state.has(receiver)) throw new TypeError("Cannot write private member to an object whose class did not declare it");
    return (kind === "a" ? f.call(receiver, value) : f ? f.value = value : state.set(receiver, value)), value;
};
var __classPrivateFieldGet = (this && this.__classPrivateFieldGet) || function (receiver, state, kind, f) {
    if (kind === "a" && !f) throw new TypeError("Private accessor was defined without a getter");
    if (typeof state === "function" ? receiver !== state || !f : !state.has(receiver)) throw new TypeError("Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it");
    return kind === "m" ? f : kind === "a" ? f.call(receiver) : f ? f.value : state.get(receiver);
};
var _aClass_jsPrivate;
class aClass {
    constructor(a, b, c, d) {
        _aClass_jsPrivate.set(this, void 0);
        __classPrivateFieldSet(this, _aClass_jsPrivate, a, "f");
        this.tsPrivate = b;
        this.tsProtected = c;
        this.tsPublic = d;
    }
    get jsPrivate() { return __classPrivateFieldGet(this, _aClass_jsPrivate, "f"); }
    ;
}
_aClass_jsPrivate = new WeakMap();
console.log(new aClass(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

I'm not sure if I did all correct, but I notice that the js style private member is now in the global scope, and also the members declared using typescript modifiers are now all public, although theoretically any attempt to access a private member should be caught while compiling to javascript, I'm not sure that's the best for code security.

Do you have any advice on which one is the best way to modify member visibility?

Could you also explain to me why there are those differences?

Comment: Looks like the TS compiler isn't using the JS `private` feature. 
Either way, use what you like to use. It doesn't really make a difference if you're programming in TS, as the compiler will take care of visibility / access issues.

Comment: "*since ES6 Javascript allow the use of the prefix "#" to a class member or method in order to achieve the same result.*" 1. it's not ES6, this is a very recent change that's not officially out yet. 2. It's only for *private* access, there is no "protected" access level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript private field syntax `#`

#### Support

This is *not* official yet. The syntax is included in [the latest upcoming draft of the specifications](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-PrivateIdentifier). However, the [ES2021 specification (ES12)](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/) does not have it. So *right now* it is in a transitioning state to become official.

In the meantime, not all browsers support private fields. Most notably Firefox version 89 (as of writing this, current version for the browser) does not support it. The upcoming version 90 would add support for private fields but it is in Beta.

#### Access level

Private field syntax only allows *hiding* a field. There is no notion in JavaScript for **protected** access (only visible to descendants of the class). So for any code outside the class, a field is either visible to anybody or not visible. Nothing in between.

In addition, private fields in JavaScript are *completely* hidden. There is no official mechanism for extracting and interacting with them programmatically from the outside. Only the class that declared it can use them.

```js
class Foo {
  #id;
  constructor(num)   { this.#id = num; }
  viewPrivate(other) { return other.#id; }
}

class Bar {
  #id;
  constructor(num) { this.#id = num; }
}

const foo1 = new Foo(1);
const foo2 = new Foo(2);

console.log(foo1.viewPrivate(foo1)); //1
console.log(foo1.viewPrivate(foo2)); //2

const bar = new Bar(3);
console.log(foo1.viewPrivate(bar)); //Error 
                                    // cannot access #x from different class
```

### TypeScript access modifiers

#### Support

The TypeScript access modifiers are technically supported everywhere. That is because the TypeScript code is converted to plain JavaScript. The compiler can be configured which ECMAScript version should be targetted.

As with other parts of the type system, the access modifiers will be stripped at compile time. If you tried to access a field where you should not be able to, you would get a compilation error.

#### Access level

The biggest difference is the support for **protected** access level to allow a field to be reachable from subclasses:

```js
class Foo {
    public    a = 1;
    protected b = 2;
    private   c = 3;
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    doStuff(): number {
        return this.a + //OK - it's public
               this.b + //OK - it's protected and Bar extends Foo
               this.c;  //Error - it's private
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEBiB7RsDexadgBwK4CMwBLELWCWAXlgEYBuDLbAJ0QBcBTETgE1nyqwATAzIsiANwicspagGYGAX2ChIMWACEIzWBwAenAHY84SFOjI9EAZTa4AZg4AUASgBcsI7gC2+DrqWZFjMHPbMRrBsABZEUAB0FADUsAD0qQDyANKwALSwRGwA5HB4hCSMwVWYMXHxAinp2XkFxaWsnNwcfBAmWjp6hhwmZsiV1cG1CSB0mOkAosysuvmFJTjMktIc4ypKQA)

---

Another big difference compared to plain JavaScript is that TypeScript access modifiers can be *changed* in subclasses to be less restrictive:

```js
class A {
    protected x = "hello";
}

class B extends A {
    public x = "world";
}

console.log(new A().x); // Compilation error
console.log(new B().x); // OK
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4CcD2AXApsAQCbQAe0AvNAEQAW+II2NA3EgL5JKiQwBC0fGQIA7YjHjI0GAK4AjEAEtg5KrQDu2TCGJtO3YNlERsIfADpmAcwAUo-Bri2AlBbIvW0APTfoAYWwAW3QlcFwlYyFMHEweY1NzK2w7Byd+V3dPHz8AeQBpJCA)

---

Finally, I have to double down on how different JavaScript's private fields are to TypeScript's `private` access modifier. TypeScript does not "hide" fields. It prevents you from referencing them. The fields still exist and could be accessed normally by code. Even compilation errors can be prevented:

```js
class Foo {
    private secret = "top secret";
}

const foo = new Foo();

console.log(JSON.stringify(foo)); //"{"secret":"top secret"}" 
console.log((foo as any).secret); //"top secret"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQA4CcCWAbmAC4Cm0EpwOpx0AvNAETHxYVU3FMDcqAvqlTB4AOwh0AZogbRRpAO5xEACgCUfYWIjwQpAHQh4AcxUApAMoB5AHL6J+UcbySAniunw1G6AHpfTMhMlNS0TABcLGwcodz8TNBa4roGRqYeMpDQYKKuavactD7+UewhXAlAA)

This cannot happen with the private field syntax in JavaScript. Again, there private fields are completely hidden from the outside.

### Which one to use

This is down to choice. If writing OOP focused TypeScript code, you might want to just stick to `private`, `protected`, `public` keywords. They play nicer with the class hierarchies.

With that said, the private field syntax `#` in JavaScript can be really powerful if you want stronger encapsulation that will not leak out.

You can also mix the two types of encapsulation.

At the end of the day, it would be case-by-case basis for each.

Comment: @VLAZ you should probably update this answer the # notation for private fields is now in all evergreen browsers
https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_fields
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the case of using private vs # sintax, IMHO the # sintax is the best approach because its values can not be inspected vs ts private which is just a compile check, now that the # syntax is fully supported in all browsers I don't see a reason to use ts private. Regarding the differences and why use one over another  it is very well explained in the ts 3.8 release notes bellow:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#ecmascript-private-fields

To add one more small reason, I like that the # affect the name (besides making it private) eg. #myField can only be referenced as this.#myField, this helps in setters because solves the problem of prefixing the private variable name with things like underscore so it won't clash with the setter name

Regarding support is now supported by all browsers see:

Can I use: https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_fields

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility

Comment: @VLAZ, I updated my answer to be more clear in why I prefer it thanks, I had some problems updating my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

The use of prefix "#" is fairly new and not officially available. If you use it browser compatablity might be an issue as well. So I would suggest you to use typescript's types for now as it is stable and takes care of cross browser support by itself.
Also, you don't have a protected access modifier in JS as of now anyways.

Comment: according to the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility) it looks like that there are problems only when used on Samsung Internet browser for fields in mobile and Safari for methods both in mobile and desktop, the remaining browsers seem to handle it pretty well, then of course for the protected ones the only option is the typescript way.

Comment: Yes, but you also sometimes need to see the industry standards. I haven't seen many open source projects use it as of now.

Comment: @MicheleNuzzi The [current version of Firefox is 89](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/) and that [doesn't support private fields](https://i.imgur.com/2LMqRP4.png). Version 90 which is upcoming will finally support them. So, *right now* it doesn't even work for normal FF users. It wouldn't work for FF ESR users for probably a while. I wouldn't say that's handled "pretty well"